# Run SharePoint 2013 VM from Windows 7 host

Tags: 2013, vmware

Is there any way I can run a SharePoint 2013 VM from Windows 7 host machine. The host machine details are:
O/S: Windows 7 Professional with SP1
Processor: i7
RAM 16GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you are living on the edge RAM wise. So do not have more service applications et.c than you need :)

There are tons of guides on how to do it, like [this one](http://wp.ahcheng.com/2013/04/21/setting-up-a-single-box-sharepoint-2013-virtual-machine/), using VMWare

Comment: Can you share some details on how can i do that. Are there any steps to make it work on Windows 7

Comment: What do you mean, to make it work? You would need a tool for running VM:s, like Virtual Box etx. Then you just need to create a new VM, configure it as you would with any SharePoint environment (but with just the Service Applications you need)